# How to centre slick carousel images?

Tags: css, carousel, slick.js

I am trying to centre my slick carousel images. I have used margin: 0 auto; and defined the width however it is still off centre as illustrated in the image 
[image]

Here is my pen https://codepen.io/SashaSashaSasha/pen/MWgepEe

Can anyone help me figure this out been stuck for a minute

```
.carousel {  
  max-height:100%; 
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px auto;
  display: block;
}

.carousel div {  
  width:100%; 
  height: 100%;  
}

.carouselWrapper {
    margin: 80px 0px 40px 0px;
    height: 80vh;
    max-width: 100%;
    display: block;

}

.slick-slide{
  margin: 0px auto;
  display: block;
}

.slick-slide img{
  max-width:100% ;
  max-height:100%;
  object-fit: contain;
  display: block;
 margin: 0px auto;
}
```

Comment: Add `.slick-list, .draggable{
  padding: 0 !important;
}`

Comment: Perfect, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is excess padding on slick container. Try this to include in you CSS style

```
.slick-list.draggable 
{    
padding: 0px 0px !important;
}
```